# Strange 1H-NMR signals/signal ratio

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

[Fedorov et al.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/B:RUCB.0000030813.05424.1f) assign the $^1$H-NMR ($\ce{CDCl3}$) chemical shifts of the $\ce{CH2}$ group in 2-(bromomethyl)phenylboronic acid

[image: 2-(bromomethyl)phenylboronic acid]

to three singlets at $4.75$, $5.09$ and $5.15~\ce{ppm}$ in a ratio of $3:3:14$.

Can someone explain their reasoning?

Comment: Could you post the entire 1H-NMR analysis? The article is behind a paywall for me, and perhaps there is something in the rest of the data that is helpful.

Comment: Regarding long's answer - do you still want this information?

Comment: Nope. I was going to try to partially blame the potential NMR-activity of $\ce{^{11}B}$, which is a spin $\frac{3}{2}$, but I forgot about the tendency of boronic acids to oligomerize.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The paper specifically addresses this issue and ascribes it to the tendency for boronic acids to exist as solvent and concentration dependent oligomers:

> The dependence of the intensity ratio for these signals and the
>   chemical shifts in the 1H NMR spectra on the concentration of the
>   samples under study as well as on the nature of the solvents used
>   indicates that anhydrides of boronic acids with different degrees of
>   oligomerization can exist along with monomeric forms of these
>   derivatives (ArB(OH)2) in solutions of substituted arylboronic acids.
>   The conclusions about the existence of oligomeric forms of boronic
>   acids and the absence of byproducts in the compounds isolated are
>   supported by the results published earlier.

This type of equilibrium can be expressed like:
[image]

Higher order oligomers are also possible.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I tend to overlook the "real" contents when searching for experimental data.